# Getting Geographical position for a non-GPS j2me phone

Tags: c#, ruby, jruby

Hi is there any way to get the geographical position of a non-GPS enabled phone through a j2me aplpication. I tried to use the JSR179 location API to do this, but I was only able to get it to work on a GPS enabled phone. 
I also read that doing this is possible on a non-gps phone by getting the cell-ID of the phone, but what do I do after I get that cell ID information. 
if anyone has a sample code to do this for example on a blackberry phone that will be really helpful.

Comment: your tags are not very well chosen

Answer (score 0):

Getting the cellid is trivial. After that you need to use on online service to match them again geographical locations (e.g. london). Having this kind of database in your app is way too big

Comment: @reiner Can you enumerate such online services, that work for this?

Comment: http://celldb.org/aboutapi.php, google ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598696/google-maps-cellid-to-location ), https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/mobile-location/documentation/cell-id-look-up-api, opencellid.org